# esp8266 reset - power consumption

Tags: power, esp8266, reset

I am working on project with esp8266 UC powered with 3.7v lithium ion battery, where the reset pin is pulled low to keep it OFF.

I would like to know if my battery were to be consumed with this method or it is like powering off the MCU, and then there is no power consumption.

Comment: Well i've done some tests with my multimeter and i found that putting esp8266 in deep sleep mode consume less than holde the reset button pressed / pulled low.

Comment: Direct connection to such a cell is out of spec to begin with, you have provided no details of surrounding circuitry which could make it work

Comment: there is one reset pin in esp8266, the board reset when it pulled low, i was wondering if the reset is like disconnecting the power supply: and i found that when the reset pin is pressed the board still consume battery energy, by the board i mean the esp8266 chip ( not nodemcu ..)